# Constantly repeating timer in an asp.net ajax page

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, timer

Today I had my first test with the ASP.NET AJAX Timer Control, in hope that it would allow me to constantly keep updating my site.

At the moment, it just updates once; this does not match the behavior of the previous .NET timers.

Was the AJAX Timer control only made to update an item once? Or do I need to use another framework?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, it updates regularly. Make sure your timer is Enabled and the Interval is set correctly, and try putting it in an UpdatePanel. Works for my page * link in profile page.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to check your implementation against what is described in [this tutorial on MSDN (Walkthrough)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398787.aspx).

*"The Timer control can work as a trigger either inside or outside an UpdatePanel control. This example shows how to use the Timer control inside an UpdatePanel control. For an example of using a Timer control as a trigger outside an UpdatePanel control, see Walkthrough: Using the ASP.NET Timer Control with Multiple UpdatePanel Controls."*

Answer (score 0):

Look at the setInterval function.  A good explanation of it is [here.](http://javascript.about.com/library/blstvsi.htm)